# Get item of column from table 1 if it matches all items of columns from table 2

Tags: sql

table 1 has 2 columns

```
C1 | C2
-------
A  | 1A
A  | 2A
A  | 3A
B  | 1B
B  | 2B
C  | 1C
D  | 1D
D  | 2D
D  | 3D
D  | 4D
```

table 2 has 2 columns

```
ID | C2
1  | 1A
1  | 2A
1  | 3A
1  | 1B
2  | 1D
2  | 2D
3  | 1C
4  | 1A
4  | 1B
```

RETURN 1, A AND 3,C because 1 matches all items in A and 3 matches all items in C

Comment: Can you please post what you already tried and the problems you are encountering?

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that the values are unique in each column, then the key idea is doing a join on the *second* column in the table followed by aggregation.

A `having` clause can count the number of matches and be sure that it matches the expected number in the first table:

```
select t1.c1, t2.c1
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.c2 = t2.c2
group by t1.c1, t2.c1
having count(*) = (select count(*) from t1 tt1 where tt1.c1 = t1.c1);
```